# How can I create a button that stops the cell currently being calculated?

Tags: button, key

How can I create a button that stops the cell currently being calculated?

Comment: `Button["Abort", FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[ "EvaluatorAbort"]]]`

Comment: It was very helpful. Thank you.